# Getting Error Could Not Connect to display

Tags: python-3.x, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I am trying to to use pdfkit in python to generate pdf from string . But its not working . But then I get the following error :-

***OSError: No wkhtmltopdf executable found: "b''"***

I am using ubuntu 16 and python3.6.6

I installed the wkhtmltopdf by using ***sudo apt-get wkhtmltopdf*** and tried implementing the pdfkit again , but then I get the error ***COULD NOT CONNECT THE X DISPLAY*** .

I also tried putting **export DISPLAY=:0** in environment, but still getting the error 
***COULD NOT CONNECT TO DISPLAY 0***

Answer (score 0):

you need to do `export DISPLAY=localhost:10.0`

Comment: Can you explain that further? Why should one do that?